# Vue: How to use component prop inside mapFields

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have general component and vuex store. For easy two-way binding I use [vuex-map-fields](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields). On component side it has `mapFields` method which creates get&set with mutations.
I want to pass `namespace` from vuex module with `props` but it seems to be impossible.

```
<my-component namespace="ns1" />

// my-component code
export default {
  props: ["namespace"],
  computed: {
    ...mapFields(??this.namespace??, ["attr1", "attr2"])
  }
}
```

Of course, there is no way to use `this` in such way so we don't have access to props. How can I specify namespace as prop in such case?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem (as you probably gathered) is that computed properties are constructed before `this` is available, but you can get around it by deferring resolution of the `this.namespace` property until the computed property is called (which won't happen until component construction is finished).

The concept is based on this post [Generating computed properties on the fly](https://forum.vuejs.org/t/generating-computed-properties-on-the-fly/14833/4).

The basic pattern is to use a computed with `get()` and `set()`

```js
computed: {
  foo: {
    get() { this.namespace...},
    set() { this.namespace...},
  }
}
```

but rather than type it all out in the component we can create a helper function based on the **vuex-map-fields** `mapFields()` function (see [here](https://github.com/maoberlehner/vuex-map-fields/blob/master/src/index.js#L35) for the original).

The `normalizeNamespace()` function that comes with vuex-map-fields does not support what we want to do, so we drop it and assume the namespace is always passed in (and that the store module uses the standard `getField` and `updateField` functions).

I have adapted one of the vuex-map-fields Codesandbox examples [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/oq5q7yo1k9).
Note the namespace is in `data` rather than `props` for conveniance, but `props` should work also.

**Template**

```html
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div>
      <label>foo </label> <input v-model="foo" /> <span> {{ foo }}</span>
    </div>
    <br />
    <div>
      <label>bar </label> <input v-model="bar" /> <span> {{ bar }}</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

**Helper**

```js
<script>

const mapFields2 = (namespaceProp, fields) => {
  return Object.keys(fields).reduce((prev, key) => {
    const path = fields[key];
    const field = {
      get() {
        const namespace = this[namespaceProp];
        const getterPath = `${namespace}/getField`;
        return this.$store.getters[getterPath](path);
      },
      set(value) {
        const namespace = this[namespaceProp];
        const mutationPath = `${namespace}/updateField`;
        this.$store.commit(mutationPath, { path, value });
      }
    };
    prev[key] = field;
    return prev;
  }, {});
};

export default {
  name: "App",
  data() {
    return {
      nsProp: "fooModule"
    };
  },
  computed: {
    ...mapFields2("nsProp", { foo: "foo", bar: "bar" })
  }
};
</script>
```

**Store**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";
import { getField, updateField } from "vuex-map-fields";
import App from "./App";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  modules: {
    fooModule: {
      namespaced: true,
      state: {
        foo: "initial foo value",
        bar: "initail bar value"
      },
      getters: {
        getField
      },
      mutations: {
        updateField
      }
    }
  }
});

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  store,
  template: "<App/>"
});
```