# Accessing Vue Component props from computed data

Tags: vue.js

I've put together a minimal example here: https://codesandbox.io/s/vnyol7olp0?fontsize=14

Inside **src/MyComponent.vue** I want to access `this.idx` from within the computed method being declared, but it's throwing an error saying:

`Cannot read property 'idx' of undefined`

I can't work out why `this` is undefined at that point, as it works from within other computed properties.

---

**main.js**

```
import Vue from "vue";
import Vuex from "vuex";

// Import the `getField` getter and the `updateField`
// mutation function from the `vuex-map-fields` module.
import { getField, updateField } from "vuex-map-fields";

import App from "./App";

Vue.use(Vuex);
Vue.config.productionTip = false;

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user: {
      firstName: "",
      lastName: ""
    },
    addresses: [
      {
        town: ""
      }
    ]
  },
  getters: {
    getField
  },
  mutations: {
    updateField
  }
});

/* eslint-disable no-new */
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  components: { App },
  store,
  template: "<App/>"
});
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="firstName"> {{ firstName }}<br>
    <input v-model="lastName"> {{ lastName }}<br>
    <input v-model="town"> {{ town }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapFields } from 'vuex-map-fields';

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  props: ['idx'],
  computed: {
    // When using nested data structures, the string
    // after the last dot (e.g. `firstName`) is used
    // for defining the name of the computed property.
    ...mapFields([
      'user.firstName',
      'user.lastName',
      // It's also possible to access
      // nested properties in arrays.
      'addresses[' + this.idx + '].town',
    ]),
  },
};
</script>
```

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>vuex-map-fields: Nested properties</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `src/MyComponent.vue` is blank in your link. Could you add the snippets in your question?

Comment: Whoops. I thought it auto-saved. That's been updated now.

Comment: instead of accessing `this.idx` in the mapFields function, use a read and write computed property and access the field in there. the conceptual problem with your code ist that the prop is dynamic and not yet defined when the code of mapFields is actually evaluated.

Comment: @phoet Could you please expand on that in an answer with an example of what you mean? I don't understand what you've said, it sounds like you're suggesting just moving the `this.idx` access to a separate computed field and then using that field within the mapFields function, but that wouldn't execute any later and so would have the same issue.

Comment: no, you do not use that within the map fields function. you have a regular computed property where you access the field without mapping.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My fix is a bit hacky but it works, it was based on the answer to this question:

[Vue: How to use component prop inside mapFields](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54833150/vue-how-to-use-component-prop-inside-mapfields)

**vuex-map-fields-prefixed.js**

```
export const mapFieldsPrefixed = function(prefix, fields) {
  return fields.reduce((prev, field) => {
    const fieldFunctions = {
      get() {
        const getterPath = 'getField';
        const pathPrefix = eval(prefix)
        const path = pathPrefix + field
        return this.$store.getters[getterPath](path);
      },
      set(value) {
        const mutationPath = 'updateField';
        const pathPrefix = eval(prefix)
        const path = pathPrefix + field
        this.$store.commit(mutationPath, { path, value });
      }
    };
    prev[field] = fieldFunctions;
    return prev;
  }, {});
}
```

**MyComponent.vue**

```
<script>
  import { mapFieldsPrefixed } from './vuex-map-fields-prefixed';

  const prefix = "'addresses[' + this.idx + '].'"
  const fields = [
    "town"
  ]

  export default {
    name: 'my-component',
    props: ['idx'],
    computed: {
      ...mapFieldsPrefixed(prefix, fields)
    }
  }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are not insisting in using vuex-map-state module, I would recommend you to using [getter function in high order function](https://vuex.vuejs.org/guide/getters.html#method-style-access).

The main idea of high order getter function, is store a function without being called, untill you passed a parameters inside. I think that will be suitable for your for passing idx as a props into MyComponent.vue.

Also, since you are using v-model to bind the value, you need to add a [setter and getter value in computed](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html#Computed-Setter).

```js
// in store.js

const store = new Vuex.Store({
    // others state getter and mutations.
    getters: {
      getField,
      getStoreAddr(state) {
        return function(idx) {
          const defaultIdx = idx || 0;
          return state.addresses[defaultIdx].town;
        };
      }
    },
    mutations: {
      updateField,
      updateStoreAddr(state, { idx, town }) {
        const defaultIdx = idx || 0;
        state.addresses[defaultIdx].town = town;
      }
    }

})
```

```js
// in MyComponent.vue script block

computed: {
    town: {
        // define getter and setter function to bind the value.
        get() {
            return this.$store.getters.getStoreAddr(this.idx)
        },
        set(town) {
            const idx = this.idx
            return this.$store.commit('updateStoreAddr', {idx, town})
        }
    }
}
```

The whole complete code is here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/4x1qw7pmlw

Hope I can solve your problem!

Comment: The amount of extra code needed for every field I want to access from VueX is the reason that I need the vuex-map-state package. My actual application has a few hundred fields I need to map, and that's a lot of code where it's possible to make mistakes when repeating myself that many times. From a maintainability perspective, that unfortunately won't work for my use case.